# Pandas transform back function that returns an array the same length as the input group

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for bad title. Please edit to make sense.

There's a lot of code below. Don't worry. It's just for a minimal example.

What I want to do is group data by label, apply my function (which checks coordinates for a given label are inside or outside an ellipse). This returns a true/false array the same length as the data. I would like to change the label to `-1` if it's outside of the ellipse.

Playing around with `apply` and `transform` the furthest I can get is

```
label
1    [True, True, False, True, False, False, True, ...
2    [False, False, True, True, False, False, True,...
dtype: object
```

But how do I transform this back into the original dataframe, and set the label to -1 for every `False` encountered?

The commented bit in the bottom shows how it works for no labels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches
import pandas as pd

def _plot_ellipse(xdata, ydata, n_std, ax = None, return_ax = False, **kwargs):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    xdata : array-like
    ydata : array-like
    n_std : scalar
        Number of sigmas (e.g. 2 for 95% confidence interval)
    ax : ax to plot on
    return_ax : bool
        Returns axis for plot
    return_inside : bool
        Returns a list of True/False for inside/outside ellipse
    **kwargs
        Passed to matplotlib.patches.Ellipse. Color, alpha, etc..

    Returns
    -------
    Ellipse with the correct orientation, given the data


    Example
    -------
    x = np.random.randn(100)
    y = 0.1 * x + np.random.randn(100)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax, in_out = _plot_ellipse(x, y, n_std = 2, ax = ax, alpha = 0.5, return_ax = True)
    ax.scatter(x, y, c = in_out)
    plt.show()

    """

    def _eigsorted(cov):
        vals, vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
        order = vals.argsort()[::-1]
        return vals[order], vecs[:, order]

    points = np.stack([xdata, ydata], axis = 1) # Combine points to 2-column matrix
    center = points.mean(axis = 0)      # Calculate mean for every column (x,y)

    # Calculate covariance matrix for coordinates (how correlated they are)
    cov = np.cov(points, rowvar = False)  # rowvar = False because there are 2 variables, not nrows variables

    vals, vecs = _eigsorted(cov)

    angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(*vecs[:,0][::-1]))
    width, height = 2 * n_std * np.sqrt(vals)

    in_out = _is_in_ellipse(xdata = xdata, ydata = ydata, center = center, width = width, height = height, angle = angle)

    if return_ax:
        ellip = patches.Ellipse(xy = center, width = width, height = height, angle = angle, **kwargs)
        if ax is None:
            ax = plt.gca()
        ax.add_artist(ellip)
        return ax, in_out
    else:
        return in_out

def _is_in_ellipse(xdata, ydata, center, width, height, angle):
    """
    Determines whether points are in ellipse, given the parameters of the ellipse

    Parameters
    ----------
    xdata : array-like
    ydata : array-lie
    center : array-like, tuple
        center of the ellipse as (x,y)
    width : scalar
    height : scalar
    angle : scalar
        angle in degrees

    Returns
    -------
    List of True/False, depending on points being inside/outside of the ellipse
    """

    cos_angle = np.cos(np.radians(180-angle))
    sin_angle = np.sin(np.radians(180-angle))

    xc = xdata - center[0]
    yc = ydata - center[1]

    xct = xc * cos_angle - yc * sin_angle
    yct = xc * sin_angle + yc * cos_angle

    rad_cc = (xct**2/(width/2)**2) + (yct**2/(height/2)**2)

    in_ellipse = []
    for r in rad_cc:
        in_ellipse.append(True) if r <= 1. else in_ellipse.append(False)

    return in_ellipse


# For a single label
# x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
# y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
# labels = [1] * len(x)
#
# df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y, "label" : labels})
#
# ax, in_out = _plot_ellipse(df.x, df.y, 2, return_ax = True, alpha = 0.5)
# ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, c = in_out)
# plt.show()


# For multiple labels
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
labels1 = [1] * 50
labels2 = [2] * 50
labels = labels1 + labels2

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y, "label" : labels})

df = df.groupby("label").apply(lambda group: _plot_ellipse(xdata = group["x"], ydata = group["y"], n_std = 1, return_ax = False))

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So heres a way that will work, I might re-factor a bit more if I was doing it but you'll get the idea and you can go from there. I've commented out your return_ax logic for simplicity.

You don't need the lambda on your `groupby.apply` because you've already defined the function as `_plot_ellipse`. You can pass `apply` a python callable as well as kwargs (these will be passed to your callable).

The line would look like

```
df = df.groupby("label").apply(_plot_ellipse, n_std = 1, return_ax = False)
```

In your function the first argument passed by pandas will be the group. So you don't need to reference the `x` and `y` variable in your function parameters. Also to get a `DataFrame` back from an `apply` function you need to return a `DataFrame` in this case you'll modify your group and then return the group. The passed group gets an attribute called `name` from pandas (group name) which in your case will just be the label. I changed the first lines of your function to this so the same code can be kept

```
xdata = grp.x
ydata = grp.y
label = grp.name
```

Then I've modified your code for `_is_in_ellipse` passing in the labels and then either keeping the label or changing it to -1. After I've reassigned `grp.label` to be the result

Your full example with modifications is below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches
import pandas as pd

def _plot_ellipse(grp, n_std, ax = None, return_ax = False, **kwargs):   
    xdata = grp.x
    ydata = grp.y
    label = grp.name

    def _eigsorted(cov):
        vals, vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
        order = vals.argsort()[::-1]
        return vals[order], vecs[:, order]

    points = np.stack([xdata, ydata], axis = 1) # Combine points to 2-column matrix
    center = points.mean(axis = 0)      # Calculate mean for every column (x,y)

    # Calculate covariance matrix for coordinates (how correlated they are)
    cov = np.cov(points, rowvar = False)  # rowvar = False because there are 2 variables, not nrows variables

    vals, vecs = _eigsorted(cov)

    angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(*vecs[:,0][::-1]))
    width, height = 2 * n_std * np.sqrt(vals)

    in_out = _is_in_ellipse(label = label, xdata = xdata, ydata = ydata, center = center, width = width, height = height, angle = angle)

#     if return_ax:
#         ellip = patches.Ellipse(xy = center, width = width, height = height, angle = angle, **kwargs)
#         if ax is None:
#             ax = plt.gca()
#         ax.add_artist(ellip)
#         return ax, in_out
#     else:
#         return in_out

    grp.label = in_out
    return grp

def _is_in_ellipse(label, xdata, ydata, center, width, height, angle):
    cos_angle = np.cos(np.radians(180-angle))
    sin_angle = np.sin(np.radians(180-angle))

    xc = xdata - center[0]
    yc = ydata - center[1]

    xct = xc * cos_angle - yc * sin_angle
    yct = xc * sin_angle + yc * cos_angle

    rad_cc = (xct**2/(width/2)**2) + (yct**2/(height/2)**2)

#     in_ellipse = []
#     for r in rad_cc:
#         in_ellipse.append(True) if r <= 1. else in_ellipse.append(False)

    return pd.Series(rad_cc).apply(lambda r: label if r <= 1. else -1)


# For a single label
# x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
# y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
# labels = [1] * len(x)
#
# df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y, "label" : labels})
#
# ax, in_out = _plot_ellipse(df.x, df.y, 2, return_ax = True, alpha = 0.5)
# ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, c = in_out)
# plt.show()


# For multiple labels
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
labels1 = [1] * 50
labels2 = [2] * 50
labels = labels1 + labels2

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y, "label" : labels})

df = df.groupby("label").apply(_plot_ellipse, n_std = 1, return_ax = False)
```

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks! Question though: now you're forcing the dataframe to have certain column names. Of course it's one line of code to rename them, but in an ideal world, wouldn't it be possible to pass specific columns for x and y columns to Pandas `apply`? I understand that this is much simpler, because it only takes a single input.

Comment: You can always pass column names as kwargs in the apply and then use `grp[MY_COL_NAME]` in your function for the that flexibility.